# Difference between two implementations of atan2 when using UIAcceleration

Tags: iphone

What is the difference between atan2(x, y) and atan2(y, x) in acceleration code (iphone)...

Can you tell me briefly ?

Comment: What acceleration code are you talking about?  Your question is not very clear.

Comment: Bubble level apple sample code

Answer (score 0):

according to wikipedia, arctangent gives you the angle between the x-axis and the point specified (I'm assuming the line is going through the origin).

which means that `atan2(x,y) = 90 - atan2(y,x)`

maybe.